# R.java error: Class file collision

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm developing an android application, and I keep getting this error:

> Class file collision: A resource exists with a different case: '/Fit Fray/bin/classes/com/a/ff/act/R$String.class'.

I had previously 'fixed' it by playing around with some layout ids, but I then end up with this error:

> Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: '...' in project '...' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file SP-Reversi Build path Build Path Problem

I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, restarting eclipse and creating a fresh project but it seems to be happening with all the new projects I create.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I know this is an old question. 
But I eventually went with re-installing any related packages. Not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I still have the same error sometimes (after exporting, cleaning or building the app, when creating a new project, or after closing eclipse and opening it again). I found out the error **can** be resolved by going into R.java and removing the commented lines at the top. Then close the file, it will be regenerated and this **can** resolve the error. If it doesn't try again. It's really annoying to have to do this all the time, especially since it sometimes takes multiple tries before the error goes away, but at least I can compile again. It would be great if someone has a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem i fixed it: 
I can be occurring due to:
Case 1. Frequent Change in names of XML files  or .java files or  custom id's eg: instead of  `@+id/myid -->@+classname/myid and referenced as (R.Classname.myid)`.
Case 2. Id's with same name in the same xml or different ones.

Solution: 
Case 1. Mostly due to custom id's Check for all the views should have `@+classname/myid` instead of `@+id` .
Case 2. Multiple Resources shares same id's or vise-versa  so give unique names to id's and eliminate any redundancy. Clean and run.